# WiX: Extracting Binary-string in Custom Action yields string like "???good data"

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3, dtf

I just found a weird behavior when attempting to extract a string from the Binary table in the MSI.

I have a file containing `Hello world`, the data I get is `???Hello world`. (Literary question mark.)

Is this as intended?
Will it always be exactly 3 characters in the beginning?

---

Sample code:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CustomAction2(Session session)
{
    View v = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT `Name`,`Data` FROM `Binary`");
    v.Execute();

    Record r = v.Fetch();
    int datalen = r.GetDataSize("Data");
    System.IO.Stream strm = r.GetStream("Data");
    byte[] rawData = new byte[datalen];
    int res = strm.Read(rawData, 0, datalen);
    strm.Close();

    String s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawData);
    // s == "???Hello World"

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess, but if you created the file using Notepad, couldn't that just be your [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)?

Comment: Could be. After a while the problem "disappeared" by itself.
Perhaps I saved the file with another editor, which didn't add a byte order mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawData);
if (s.Length > 0 && s[0] == '\uFEFF')
{
    s = s.Substring(1);
}
```

instead of `String s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawData);`